# how to properly configure meteor to work with node file uploading module 'multer'

Tags: node.js, meteor, multer

I'm just starting with meteor.

I've found, and added the 'multer' package:

```
meteor add pfafman:multer
```

Now, I wonder how to configure the server side of meteor to use.

In my plain node app, I use it like this:

```
app.use(multer({ dest: './uploads/',
        rename: function (fieldname, filename) {
            return filename+Date.now();
        },
        onFileUploadStart: function (file) {
            console.log(file.originalname + ' is starting ...');
        },
        onFileUploadComplete: function (file) {
            console.log(file.fieldname + ' uploaded to  ' + file.path);
            var fileName = file.name;
            var done=true;
        }
    }));
```

What is the equivalent server code for this in Meteor?

Answer (score 5):

pfafman's multer is nothing more than a wrapper around npm's multer (if you go through [its source](https://github.com/pfafman/meteor-multer) you'd realize all it really does is

```
multer = Npm.require('multer');
```

and then export it as a global variable through `api.export('multer');` (He didn't even include any test cases, let along a demo.))

In express, `app.use()` is used for adding middleware 'layers' to the middleware stack. Since now `multer` is already a global variable accessible anywhere on the server (after you have `meteor add pfafman:multer`), you can just use it the way you do in express by calling it in `Meteor.startup`:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    multer({ dest: './uploads/',
        rename: function (fieldname, filename) {
            return filename+Date.now();
        },
        onFileUploadStart: function (file) {
            console.log(file.originalname + ' is starting ...');
        },
        onFileUploadComplete: function (file) {
            console.log(file.fieldname + ' uploaded to  ' + file.path);
            var fileName = file.name;
            var done=true;
        }
    })
  });
}
```

Note: this would create the `uploads` directory in

```
YourMeteorProject/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/
```